# Calculating a derivative from a Maclaurin series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm attempting to find $f^{(100)}(x)$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. The Maclaurin series is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}$.

I figure that $(-1)^nx^{2n}=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)\;x^n}{n!}$. Setting $n=100$,

$x^{200}=\frac{f^{(100)}(0)\;x^{100}}{100!}$

$f^{(100)}(0)=x^{100}100!$

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, because that should be a numerical answer (in fact, it should be $100!$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting was wrong: it should be $$(-1)^nx^{2n}=\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$
So $f^{(100)}=(-1)^{50}(100)!=(100)!$.
Tell me if I miss something. Thanks in advance.
**P.S.** In case it is still ambiguous, let explain more:
$\sum\limits_0^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}$ in fact is equal to $\sum\limits_0^{\infty}\text{Re}(i^n)x^n$, where $\text{Re}$ means to take the real part of a comple number. Now you can see what the terms of the series are, and find out why the $2n$-th term is $(-1)^nx^{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but why? Isn't the $n$th term of a Maclaurin series always $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)\;x^n}{n!}$?

Comment: And the $n$-th term corresponds to $x^n$.So you related one $2n$-th term with an $n$-th term.

Comment: Is it still ambiguous? If so, I shall make some modifications. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I'm still not sure why having $2n$ in the exponent makes it the $2n$th term. When did it switch from being the $n$th to the $2n$th?

Comment: Because the $n$-th is $0$ unless $n$ is even. This is what the sum $\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}$ means.

Comment: What do you mean? The terms for $n=1$, $n=3$, $n=5$, etc. are not zero.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8056/discussion-between-awllower-and-hypercube)